# Hide shipping method working with Innozilla Per Product Shipping WooCommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, methods

Hi all :) I understand that there are a lot of such topics, but, unfortunately, I cannot apply any code, and I do not know how to redo and apply it.
I added an additional shipping method for specific countries using the Innozilla Per Product Shipping WooCommerce plugin for a specific product
when selecting a specific country, I see old shipping methods like flexible_shipping_9_2, flat_rate: 12 and + new "per_product" shipping method
I would like to hide all delivery methods except per_product when the per_product delivery method is used.
How to do it? Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
   
function businessbloomer_hide_free_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
   $shipping_class_target = 15; // shipping class ID 
   $in_cart = false;
   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
      if ( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
         $in_cart = true;
         break;
      } 
   }
   if ( $in_cart ) {
      unset( $rates['free_shipping:8'] ); // shipping method with ID 
   }
   return $rates;
}
```

Comment: i solved my problem with this code, use class instead of plugins